# Access AWS service connection credentials and map to environment in azure pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to access the AWS access and secret key from the AWS service connection and map them to the environment variables of a task. I have already set up an AWS service connection into my azure pipeline.

Something like

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run Desktop App Builder'
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWSServiceConnection.SecretKey)    # map to environment variable
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWSServiceConnection.SecretAccessKey)
  inputs:
    command: 'run'
    projects: 'AppBuilder\AppBuilder.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release -- build desktop production'
```

I have read the docs and I have seen that is the correct way to map a secret to environment variable by using the *env* keyword. But I am unsure of how to fetch the AWS secret and access key using the AWS service connection

Comment: you can have a look the variable synthax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline

Comment: You can try using the Service endpoint API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get-service-endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP) but I highly doubt it will return the `Secret Access Key` since it is protected